# How do i print a list of string and integers vertically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am trying to print out a list of string and integers vertically.

`map = [["SG", 8], ["MY", 8], ["PH", 8], ["ID", 8], ["TH", 8]]`

the print should return:

```
SG        8
MY        8
PH        8
ID        8
TH        8
```

this is what i have :

```
for element in map:
  print(element)
```

the failed output:

```
    ['SG',       8]  
    ['MY',       8]  
etc....
```

Comment: `for x, y in map: print(x, y)`?

Comment: So you are asking "how to print ``element = ["SG", 8]`` as ``SG        8`` instead of ``["SG", 8]``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes sir that is correct

Comment: `for element in map:` / `print('%-8s %2d" % tuple(element)`)

Comment: @TimRoberts favor f-strings or `.format` over the old-style string formatting

Comment: You can if you want.  `printf` formatting expresses the concept very clearly here.

Comment: Here is a very good website to learn about Python string formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: @TimRoberts the problem is that old-style is less feature complete and has potentially confusing behavior regarding how `tuple`s are treated. It is slightly different, but is what you propose really more clear than: `for symbol, number in map: print(f"{symbol:<8} {number:>2}")`? But again, the point is having to avoid people learning two slightly different specs

Answer (score 2):

May note be the best solution, but try this.

```
for element in map:
    print("{}\t{}".format(element[0],element[1]))
```

Comment: `element` != `i`

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I've already corrected

Comment: you can do `for a,b in map` to already unpack

Comment: yeah sure, at the end is the same. I think that the person who asked this was looking for something like the "\t" which is useful when the first element is always the same size, or something like "%-8s %2d" for other cases. That is, learning a bit of python string formatting.

Comment: i have managed to print it out vertically, now my next problem is that for every turn, i will have 2 inputs in which i have to choose  eg sg,my , my,ph, th,sg, and i would have to select 1 of them in each turn. how would i check to see if i picked sg it will print out SG 7? so basically if u picked an item, it would be deducted by 1

Comment: That is already another question. You can ask ask a new question for that.